# Не могу определиться с характеристиками арендуемого сервера

Tags: vps, сервер

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане.

В недавнем времени решил реализовать свой проект, но не могу определиться с характеристиками сервера, которые подошли бы мне на начальном этапе. Сайт написан по уму (для себя как никак), не имеет сложных запросов в БД. Мне интересно, на какое количество целевых пользователей рассчитано данное железо и сколько людей оно выдержит при хорошей активности.

Собственно, вот железо:

- Процессор Intel Xeon. 1 ядро > 2ГГц
- Оперативная память 512 мб
- Место на диске 30 гб

Заранее спасибо за предоставленные ответы!

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: мне кажется, этот вопрос можно рассматривать в свете программирования — если произвести нагрузочное тестирование сервера.

Comment: По сути указанные Вами характеристики на сегодня у подавляющего большинства хостеров минимум, что они предоставляют. Если не заморачиваться с нагрузочным тестированием и прочими расчетами, которые с большой долей вероятности не дадут Вам ничего, то мой Вам совет: периодически мониторьте в панели управления нагрузку (загрузка процессора, количество посещений, обращений к базе и т.п.). Как будете видеть, что с приростом пользователей Вы подходите к граница выделенных ресурсов, то наращивайте их (если это облачный хостинг) или переходите на следующий тарифный план по линейке.

Comment: Ну а как вариант, можно заняться разными вычислениями, грузить сайт, профилировать и т.д. Вопрос, а есть ли время и нужно ли это в Вашем случае? Потому что многие полагают, что сейчас у них будет сайт с посещаемостью с первого же дня как минимум 10К. Но это далеко не так. Да и 10K в день - это всего лишь несколько человек "одномоментно". Так что не обманывайтесь сильно :)

Answer (score 1):

> Мне интересно, на какое количество целевых пользователей рассчитано данное железо

Этот вопрос не имеет смысла. Железо не бывает рассчитанным на количество целевых пользователей, оно взаимодействует не с ними, а с ОС и ПО на вашем сервере.

Рассматривайте сервис целиком, состоящий из одного или нескольких серверов со всеми участвующими в работе сайта приложениями (вебсервер, БД, бизнес-логика, что там ещё).

Рассмотрите типичные сценарии ваших пользователей. Что они делают на сайте, какие запросы создают, как на это реагирует сайт? Соберите статистику за хотя бы несколько дней. Выделите основные сценарии — они станут основой нагрузочного тестирования.

Освойте какое-нибудь ПО для мониторинга показателей сервера. Хотя бы htop, но лучше что-нибудь, собирающее статистику в БД. (например, telegraf).

Используйте любой удобный вам генератор нагрузки (например [yandex-tank](/questions/tagged/yandex-tank), [gatling](/questions/tagged/gatling), [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter)). Исследуйте:

- Предельный RPS, на котором сайт начинает отдавать 500е или виснет.
- Поведение сайта при разных уровнях RPS до предельного значения.

  - Время ответа (смотрите на 95 и 99 процентили, а не на среднее).
  - Количество ошибок (если они почему-то есть в нормальном режиме работы)
  - Утечки памяти, диска

Подумайте насчёт SLA. Грубо говоря, установите максимально допустимое время ответа и процент ошибок (пятисотых), которые вы хотите предоставлять пользователям. Найдите RPS, на котором 99 процентиль и процент ошибок не превышают ваше SLA.

Это и есть RPS, на который рассчитан ваш сайт. Вы также можете рассматривать не запросы в секунду, а пользователей — тогда для них нужно будет смоделировать сценарии использования (частота запросов, их тип и последовательности). Это позволит вам оценить число пользователей, на которых рассчитан сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Количество пользователей в сутки равно 60 * 60 * 24 / (время обработки одного запроса).

Если код написан действительно грамотно, то результат можно умножить на количество ядер процессора.