# Инструмент для оценки эффективности сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, websocket

Необходимо создать положение, которое отправляет серверу запрос и измеряет время ответа.
 Время отклика должно быть представлено графически в виде линии времени и таблично.

Как такое можно реализовать.
Подскажите, статьи по этой теме.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется нагрузочным тестированием. Описываемое вами приложение уже существует во множестве вариантов, например [yandex-tank](/questions/tagged/yandex-tank), [gatling](/questions/tagged/gatling), [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter). Подробнее об организации нагрузочного тестирования есть например в этом ответе: [Не могу определиться с характеристиками арендуемого сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488972)

Для отображения времени отклика есть как встроенные средства, так и дополнительные инструменты. Для информативного нагрузочного тестирования вам понадобится отслеживать не только время отклика, но и использование ресурсов сервера, количество ошибок и другие показатели. Читайте, например, про ELK-стек (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana).